# Correct way for Vec type as argument in Rust

Tags: rust

While coding, I needed a function that takes a immutable `Vec` as an argument and does something.
This is the function definition:

```rust
fn my_func(list: &Vec<Type>);
```

The problem is that `Type`s have to be owned by `Vec`, but I don't care. I only care that I can access them.
I have rewritten it to be like this:

```rust
fn my_func(list: &Vec<&Type>);
```

,but then I have to do `.iter().collect()` for every `Vec<Type>` that I pass in.

Question:
What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why even use `Vec` at all? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/

Comment: It's "weird" in idiomatic Rust to take a reference to a container like that instead of a slice, `&[Type]`.  If you want to iterate over `&Type`, that's what `slice::iter` is for.

Answer (score 4):

First, you probably never want to pass a `&Vec<T>`. Except for asking for the capacity, there's nothing you can do with it that you can't also do with `&[T]`, which allows other things (like arrays) being passed in.

Second, if you want to accept either `T` or `&T`, you need a generic function.

```
fn my_func<T: Borrow<Type>>(list: &[T]) {
  for (t in list) {
    let rt : &Type = t.borrow();
  }
}
```

Third, if you want to be even more generic, you should consider taking an iterator (or `IntoIterator`) instead of a slice, if linear iteration is sufficient for your use case.

Comment: your call to borrow is missing a `()`, also in the third case i'd take `impl IntoIterator` over `impl Iterator` because the former can take both a container and an iterator.